# How to charge less than 0.5 USD using Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, subscription, laravel-cashier

I'm using Stripe for my Laravel based project. Stripe allows only 0.5 USD as the minimum value when `charge` or `checkout`. But I want to charge 0.2 USD in one-time payment in my project. I know stripe allowed only 0.5 USD as the default minimum value for payments. So I want to know is there any way or any method to charge less amount than 0.5 USD using Stripe. If anyone knows, please help me...

Comment: There isn't, because the transaction fees will be more than your revenue - why would you want to do that?

Comment: I wanted to just try with a low-value charge for a single charge because it's not a subscription. In my project, it'll be an extra charge. But now I know the reason why they not allowing it with your explanation. Thank you.

Comment: @Dai in our example, someone is ordering $70.10 and uses a $70 gift voucher. We can take a loss on the $0.10 transaction, because we already gained from the previous $70 gift card purchase. It's mad they don't allow this.

Comment: @iamkeir Uhm. Why not just choose to not charge a customer’s card if it’s not worth it? If you want to use Stripe anyway for customer details verification then you don’t need to place a charge - It’s not like you’ll be defrauded by CC if they’re already using a gift-card you’ve authenticated yourselves.

Comment: @Dai for a number of reasons but most importantly accuracy of accounts.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum charge amount for USD is 0.5. If your bank account support foreign currencies for settlement, you can charge an amount with a different currency that's equivalent to < 0.5 USD.

You can view the minimum amount for each settlement currency in this table.  https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#minimum-and-maximum-charge-amounts